# The inverse Laplace transformation of $e^s$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I am solving the differential equation:

$$y'' + 3xy' -6y = 1, \ y(0) = y'(0) = 0$$

Using Laplace transformations.

I arrived at:

$$L(y)(s) = \frac{c}{s^3} e^{s^2 / 6} + \frac1{s^3}$$

Where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. I doubt that this is what it really is, though I ran through my calculations again and nothing seemed to be wrong.

So I did:

$$L(y - \frac{x^2}2 )(s) = \frac{c}{s^3} e^{s^2/6} = L(g \star h)$$

Where:

$$L(g)(s) = \frac{c}{s^3}$$

$$L(h)(s) = e^{s^2/6}$$

Now, all I have to do is find $h$, which seems not easy at all (if possible). Not to mention that I'll have to find the convolution afterwards.

> Is there an inverse Laplace transformation for the function $u \rightarrow e^u$? How could it be found?

Thank you.

Comment: If $y(0) = 0$, then $\lim_{s \to \infty} Y(s)$ should be 0 as well (Edit: as pointed out by Juan Ospina, this can be achieved by setting $c = 0$). The positive sign on your exponential bothers me a little. I believe Laplace's transform is not the best idea when dealing with variable coefficients. Furthermore, your ODE is a Hermite differential equation, so the solutions are well-known.

Comment: @Dmoreno I certainly believe that there are better methods to tackle this ODE, but I'm currently studying Laplace transforms and this is a part of an exercise. But I don't get why: $L(y)(\infty) = 0$. Could you perhaps write down an answer explaining this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the initial value theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_value_theorem Since the initial condition is bounded, 0 indeed, then we must enforce the requirement that I commented above.

Comment: @Dmoreno: thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome @BolzWeir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to introduce the condition:

$$L \left( y \right)  \left( \infty  \right) =0$$

and then this implies that $ c = 0$.

According with this the solution is

$$y \left( x \right) ={\frac {{x}^{2}}{2}}$$

Comment: Thank you. But why is it that $L(y)(\infty) = 0$? Could you explain that please?

Comment: The laplace transform is a function of $s$ and $s$ varies from 0 to ·$\infty $.  The laplace transform must be a function with a well behavior when $s = \infty $. In other words the Laplace transform must be 0 when $s = \infty $.  Do you agree?

Comment: now I do see why. Thank you.